# How do I determine a React Native Navigation tab button's accessibility ID?

Tags: appium-ios, react-native-navigation

I'm trying to determine why one of my tests (using appium to drive a React Native app on the iOS simulator) is failing to find one of the React Native Navigation tabs in our app by the value provided as its `testID`.  The test is using `elementByAccessibilityId`, and only seems to fail when the simulator is running iOS 10.0 vs. succeeding on 10.2 and 10.3.  I'd like to verify that the [accessibilityIdentifier has been set from the testID](https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation/blob/c62d944c2b10a841e531c05b45f88f18f902042a/ios/RCCNavigationController.m#L402) correctly, but (a) the buttons do not seem to appear in the [React Developer Tools Inspector](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/debugging.html#react-developer-tools); and (b) neither the Accessibility Inspector that ships with XCode 8.3.3 nor the one that ships with 9.1 seems to display this field (though apparently [the tools for 9.1b2 did](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46897038/7783436)).

The answer I'm hoping for is either:

- How do I ensure that the correct `accessibilityIdentifier` is set on the Navigation tab buttons, so I can continue investigating why appium is unable to find the button?
- or; does anyone know why appium is able to find the tab under 10.2 & 10.3 but NOT under 10.0?  I didn't find anything via web search indicating some change to accessibility APIs across 10.0 -> 10.2.

Also, if I'm barking up the wrong tree or missing something completely separate, guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that our team is using a fork of React Native Navigation, which makes it difficult for me to determine whether this is a bug in RNN itself or was introduced into our fork.  Still unclear what the root cause is or why it would be platform specific.

However, I am able to work around this issue by using `label` instead of `testID` in the tab definition provided to RNN.  This has the side effect of adding text labels, but that is probably more correct than having no text labels anyway.